# Typescript create array from object

Tags: angular, typescript

How can I convert the following object:

```
{
  Value1: 1,
  Value2: 3
}
```

into an array that looks like this:

```
[
 {name: Value1, position: 1},
 {name: Value2, position: 3}
]
```

I've tried using `Object.keys`, but didn't really get the desired results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the array of `[key, value]` pairs using `Object.entries` function.

```js
const input = { 
 Value1: 1, 
 Value2: 3 
};

const output = Object.entries(input).map((item) => ({
  name: item[0],
  position: item[1]
}));
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function convertToArray(obj){
   return  Object.keys(obj).map(prop => {
      return {
           name: prop, 
           position: obj[prop]
      };
});

console.log(convertToArray({ Value1: 2}));
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: OK Nico. I thought would be self explanatory.